# C#.net search inside text for specific letter and add (Zero Width Non Joiner ) encoded in Unicode as U+200C

Tags: c#, .net

How can I search between characters to find specific(**هـ**)letter and add zero-width non-joiner (Unicode as U+200C) to it?

language is RTL.
for example

> Blockquote بازاڕه داخراوهکانو نهو سوێنانهی

change to this by adding u+200c

> Blockquote بازاڕه داخراوەکانو ئەو سوێنانەی

Comment: Very unclear what problem you have writing code. Regular `Replace` as shown in a duplicate should be enough. Feel free to [edit] the question with details if you believe that's is not the case.

Comment: C# doesn't think it is a letter, it is "\u0647\u0640".